# How to get React Native variant in Metro?

Tags: javascript, react-native, metro-bundler

I am developing React Native application that includes different configurations for different possible clients, in a file such as `src/config/config.js`. These configurations are quite complex. The file is structured based on the client name as key, and the values as the object entries, e.g.:

```js
export default {
  fooClient: {
    apiUrl: "https://foo.example.com/",
  barClient: {
    apiUrl: "https://bar.example.com/"
  }
}
```

Of course, there are many other option keys.

When building the app, I know for which client I want to do this, by specifying an Android build variant, e.g.:

```sh
ENVFILE=.env npx react-native run-android --variant fooDebug --appIdSuffix foo
```

For security reasons, I don't want keys of other clients to be included in the config file though. What are my options to **remove all other client configs** from this file before I build the app and ship it to a client?

I thought about the following: I modify the packager so that it strips out the keys that do not correspond to the current build variant.

I now have a transformer plugin for Metro that does the following:

```js
const upstreamTransformer = require('metro-react-native-babel-transformer');

module.exports.transform = function(src, filename, options) {
  if (typeof src === 'object') {
    // handle RN >= 0.46
    ({ src, filename, options } = src);
  }

  if (filename.endsWith('config.js')) {
    console.log('Transforming ' + filename);
    let srcStripped = src.replace(';', '').replace('export default ', '');
    let configObj = JSON.parse(srcStripped);
    // TODO: get the build variant and strip all keys that we do not need from configObj
    return upstreamTransformer.transform({
      src: 'export default ' + JSON.stringify(configObj) + ';',
      filename: filename,
      options
    });
  } else {
    return upstreamTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
  }
};
```

But how do I know which build variant is being used?

If this seems like an XY problem, I am happy to explore alternatives to building the configuration dynamically. I cannot, however, use environment variables, since the configuration will be too complex for it to be just a list of `.env` keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use Metro `transform` this way. It's not clean and it may lead to missing configuration and/or damaged syntax sooner or later.

What I have done and suggest you, is to create 3 different configuration files under `src/config/`; one file for `fooClient.js`, one file for `barClient.js` and one last file with common configuration `client.js`. All files will export default configuration objects, but inside each `fooClient` and `barClient`, you'll use [`deepmerge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge) module to merge `client.js` config:

#### `client.js`:

```js
export default {
  commonSettingA: "...",
  commonSettings: {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

#### `fooClient.js`:

```js
import merge from 'deepmerge';
import config from './config';

export default merge.all([
  config,
  {
    apiUrl: "https://foo.example.com/",
  }
]);
```

#### `barClient.js`:

```js
import merge from 'deepmerge';
import config from './config';

export default merge.all([
  config,
  {
    apiUrl: "https://bar.example.com/",
  }
]);
```

Then you can use an environment variable to pass the needed configuration and create a propriate metro resolve; [`@react-native-community/cli`](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli) does not pass command line arguments to metro config script. You can use `process.argv` to parse it by yourself, but it's not worth it.

Here is how you can create a resolve inside `metro.config.js` using environment variable:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  projectRoot: path.resolve(__dirname),

  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    extraNodeModules: {
      // Local aliases
      "@config": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/config", `${process.env.METRO_VARIANT}Client.js`)
    }
  }
};
```

Using this resolve, you'll have to import the configuration like this:

```js
import config from '@config';
```

Then you add 2 `package.json` scripts, one for `fooClient` and one for `barClient`:

```
{
   ...
  "scripts": {
    "run:android:foo": "METRO_VARIANT=foo ENVFILE=.env npx react-native run-android --variant fooDebug --appIdSuffix foo",
    "run:android:bar": "METRO_VARIANT=bar ENVFILE=.env npx react-native run-android --variant barDebug --appIdSuffix bar",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Then you just run the needed script:

```sh
yarn run:android:foo # will build with fooClient.js
```

```sh
yarn run:android:bar # will build with barClient.js
```

Comment: I'm coming back to this answer as I'm having trouble understanding how the `METRO_VARIANT` variable is actually passed to the Metro server when calling `run-android`. The Metro server should already be running at this point in time, started by `npx react-native start`, right? So how does it get the env from the `run-android` call from another shell, and decide based on that?

Comment: If you start metro server manually, then you'll have to set the environment variable to the `npx react-native start` script as well. Does this fail to pass the `METRO_VARIANT` if you leave it start metro automatically?

Comment: You were right. There was another bug masking the fact that the env was not picked up. Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a reason why passed ENVs on MacOS turn undefined in metro.config.js, but not in any other application file? When bundling on Windows, ENVs are passed correctly. I have tried passing them the way you did it / using the `cross-env` package / using `react-native-dotenv` package. The problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add a "duplicated" parameter to the command?

Like so
`METRO_VARIANT=fooDebug ENVFILE=.env npx react-native run-android --variant fooDebug --appIdSuffix foo`

And get it with `process.env.METRO_VARIANT`

You might not want to make your setup much more complex. Depending on the number of the number of different clients, you might wanna go with multiple schemas/variants per client, but that is probably way overkill.

Comment: I guess that's a quick and dirty workaround, thanks. I was hoping to learn more about how Metro is called from RN and if there could be some way to pass or access the variant.